# Using an undefined (misspelled) argument in `paste` function - understand the result

Tags: r, arguments, variadic-functions

We all know there is a `collapse` argument in `paste()` function. It refers to an optional character string to separate the results:

```
paste(1:5, collapse = ", ")  
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

But, also when the `collapse` argument is misspelled - e.g. `cpllapse` - the call doesn't error, although the result is confusing:

```
paste(1:5, cpllapse = ", ")
[1] "1 , " "2 , " "3 , " "4 , " "5 , "
```

I googled the `cpllapse` parameter in R, but could not find anything.

Why doesn't `paste()` error when using a misspelled argument, and how can the result be explained? Or is there actually a `cpllapse` parameter in `paste()`?

Comment: There's no `cpllapse` argument.  Unrecognised arguments are just variadic input.

Comment: The formal named parameters of `paste()` are `sep`, `collapse`, and `recycle0`. Others will be passed to `...` no matter what their names are. So `paste(c(1:5), cpllapse = ", ")` is equivalent to `paste(c(1:5), ", ")` or even `paste(c(1:5), anything_else = ", ")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`paste` has the ellipses `...` as its first parameter. The ellipses collects all function arguments that don't match one of `paste`'s named parameters.

The help page says:

> `...` one or more R objects, to be converted to character vectors.

You are passing two R objects and it does not matter that one of them is a named argument, due to how the ellipses and [argument matching work in R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching). As usual in R, input vectors are recycled to the length of the longest input vector.

What you are doing there is basically the same as `paste(1:5, rep(", ", 5), sep = " ")`.

Comment: Also a related section on `...` in [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments): "Using `...` comes at a price — any misspelled arguments will not raise an error, and any arguments after `...` must be fully named. This makes it easy for typos to go unnoticed"